# How to merge lines in 2 difference files(linux awk)

Tags: awk

Can you help me to merge two files?
Actually its line should be merged, and each line has the same ID(eg. 1 or 2 in this example.).

## File1

```
1#first#scott#prince01
2#second#scott#prince02
```

## File2

```
1#scott#prince01#88129
2#scott#prince02#34
```

## Final

```
1#first#scott#prince01#1#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#2#scott#prince02#34
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your simple case it would be enough to use `join` command:

```
join -t'#' File1 File2
```

The output:

```
1#first#scott#prince01#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#scott#prince02#34
```

---

- `-t'#'` - specifying field separator

Comment: OMG. Very simple. Can we use 'join' command in all other unix as well?

Comment: @Sigularity, `join` is a standard tool from GNU coreutils https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}($1 in a){print a[$1],$0}' file1 file2
1#first#scott#prince01#1#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#2#scott#prince02#34
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '        
BEGIN{ 
    FS=OFS="#"      # set FS AND OFS to #
}
NR==FNR {           # for the first file
    a[$1]=$0        # hash records, use $1 as key
    next            # skip to next record
}
($1 in a) {         # for the second file, if key found in the hash
    print a[$1],$0  # output
}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Each line should be merged with '#'. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigularity Sorry, my bad. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Some more way ( I assume files are ordered )

**Input**

```
$ cat f1
1#first#scott#prince01
2#second#scott#prince02

$ cat f2
1#scott#prince01#88129
2#scott#prince02#34
```

**Using** [pr](/questions/tagged/pr)

```
$ pr -mtJS'#' f1 f2
1#first#scott#prince01#1#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#2#scott#prince02#34
```

**Using** [paste](/questions/tagged/paste)

```
$ paste -d'#' f1 f2
1#first#scott#prince01#1#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#2#scott#prince02#34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{a[FNR]= a[FNR]=="" ? $0 :a[FNR]"#"$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' File1 File2 
1#first#scott#prince01#1#scott#prince01#88129
2#second#scott#prince02#2#scott#prince02#34
```

Brief explanation,

- store the specific value for line #FNR in a[FNR]
- `a[FNR]= a[FNR]=="" ? $0 :a[FNR]"#"$0`: save it as `$0` if no initial value was in a[FNR], store `a[FNR]"#"$0` otherwise.

Comment: It doesn't respect the ID field but FNR. If you change the order of records 1 and 2 in `file1` it produces faulty output, such as `2#second#scott#prince02#1#scott#prince01#88129`. At least add a requirement for the data to be ordered on the id field.

Comment: You'reright, this method only work while the ID is exactly same as the FNR.

Comment: what's the maximum length of string an array can hold for a key in an awk command , this command doesn't seem to work if $0 has character length greater then 1000 ( something I tried ) ?

Comment: @Vicky, if the length of $0 hit the maximum limit of `awk`, and I suggest you may try other non-awk method